# Zend Framework 1 fetch results without duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, fetch

I'm trying to fetch records from MySQL DB without duplicates.
My Table looks like this:

```
id | name
1  | test
2  | test1 
3  | test
4  | test2
5  | test1
6  | test3
```

I'm fetching data in this way (controller):

```
$tags = new Application_Model_DbTable_Tags();
$this->view->tags = $tags->fetchAll();
```

And after displaying in view the result is: `test, test1, test, test2, test1, test3`.
What I'd like to accomplish is: `test, test1, test2` so there are no duplicates of particular records, with something like that:

```
$this->view->tags = $tags->fetchAll($tags->select()->...);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try this $tags->fetchAll($tags->select()->from($tags, array('DISTINCT name')));

Comment: For more info check [this](http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/how-to-use-distinct-for-specific-column-in-zend-framework-database-select/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` should help. Try this

```
$select = $tags->select()->distinct();
$this->view->tags = $tags->fetchAll($select);
```